# How do you check how much current a Mac USB port can deliver?

Tags: usb, power

This question is similar to the superuser question "[How to check how much power a USB port can deliver](https://superuser.com/questions/297959/how-do-you-check-how-much-power-a-usb-port-can-deliver)", which is answered for Linux and Windows.

How do you check the same on a Mac?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Knowledgebase article [Apple Computers and Displays: Powering peripherals through USB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4049) contains some general guidelines and illustrates using System Profiler (System Information in Lion) to provide information about the output (according to specifications) of a Macs USB ports.

[image]

If you want to test the real world voltage output of a given USB port on an individual Macintosh at a given load you will have to use a test device. ([USB Test Circuit](http://www.girr.org/mac_stuff/usb_stuff.html#method))

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Would be good if you could include the relevant screenshot in your answer (for later reference, if the external link goes down).

Comment: Eventually, I've added the screenshot myself.

Answer (score 6):

Simply open About this Mac -> More Info... and go to USB on the left side of System Profiler. You will get current (now power or voltage) in milliAmpere but I guess this is what you need to know. E.g.

```
USB Receiver:

  Product ID:       0xc52b
  Vendor ID:        0x046d  (Logitech Inc.)
  Version:          12.00
  Speed:            Up to 12 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer:     Logitech
  Location ID:      0xfa130000 / 6
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    98
```